# XML npp search and replace

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, xml

Bear in mind that I'm new to xml and npp..

I have a large xml file with several thousand records, and I need to change lines to make it work in an other program.

I've done most of the transformation in format, but hit a problem now.

What my xml looks like now:

```
</Value>
<name>C01</name>
<description>TEXT WITH VARYING NUBMER OF CHARACTERS FOR EACH LINE</Value>
</DPR>
```

and what i want:

```
<DPR>
<name>C01</name>
<description>TEXT WITH VARYING NUBMER OF CHARACTERS FOR EACH LINE</description>
</DPR>
```

The problem is replacing `</Value>` with two different things depending on if it is in a string of stands alone. The second problem I have is replacing parts of a line and keep the rest - when the part I want to keep has a different number of characters for every line.

All help is much appriciated!

Comment: Parsing XML with an editor is risky business. You'd be better off using a parser like XSLT or xquery. But you'd have to show a more complete sample of your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `</Value` with `</DPR>` when it exists alone in the line:

Find what: `^ *</Value>`

Replace with: `</DPR>`

Search mode: Regular expression

After that there shouldn't be any other instances of `</Value>` than those which are together with a string, so replacing them should be trivial. But for completeness...

Replacing `[somestringhere]</Value` -> `[somestringhere]</description>` when it exists alone in the line:

Find what: `^(<description>.+?)</Value>`

Replace with: `$1</description>`

Search mode: Regular expression

In the above `^` stands for the start of the line, `*` means whitespace may or may not exist, `.+?` means any characters up to the first occurrence of the string after that ([see here for more info on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)), and `$1` in the replacement string will be substituted with the matching part enclosed in parentheses in the source data.

Comment: Perfect! And thank you for the extensive answer with commentery, really helps when my current level is as low as it is!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use regular expressions in Perl:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/</Value>\n<name>/<DPR>\n<name>/' yourfile.txt
```